# Need to update multiple records at once using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel-5, eloquent

I just need to update multiple rows at time.

Am able to insert multiple rows at a time, like the code below,

```
foreach ($request->something as $key => $value) {
    $data=array(
        'db_table_field0'=> $request->form_something[$key],
        'db_table_field1'=>$request->form_something2[$key],
        'db_table_field2'=>$request->form_something3[$key],
        'db_table_field3'=>$request->form_something4[$key],
        );
        tableModel::insert($data);
 }
```

data is inserting, I tried same for update like,

```
foreach ($request->something as $key => $value) {
    $auc_det_id = tableModel::where('value', $request->value[$key])->get();

    $data=array(
        'db_table_field0'=> $request->form_something[$key],
        'db_table_field1'=>$request->form_something2[$key],
        'db_table_field2'=>$request->form_something3[$key],
        'db_table_field3'=>$request->form_something4[$key],
        );
        $auc_det_id->update($data);
 }
```

It's not updating, some error like method update not found. I also tried `save()` instead of `update()` .

I checked if null `$auc_det_id` then data is not saving(no error)

Comment: where does `auc_update` come in at?  You may want `first()` instead of `get()` to get a single model.

Comment: @aynber its `$auc_det_id` not `auc_update`

Comment: You have `$auc_det_id = tableModel`, but then you use `$auc_update->update($data);`

Comment: Whats wrong in the question? Why downvote, anyhow I don't care, I got my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
$data=array(
    'db_table_field0'=> $request->form_something[$key],
    'db_table_field1'=>$request->form_something2[$key],
    'db_table_field2'=>$request->form_something3[$key],
    'db_table_field3'=>$request->form_something4[$key],
);

tableModel::where('value', $request->value[$key])->update($data);
```

Comment: Working as I need.